# React-Navigation ,nested navigation issues

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, addeventlistener, react-native-navigation

I need to navigate between two stack groups based on a condition ( if the user allowed the permissions - navigate to a different stack group, else stay in the screen where user can allow the permissions).

1. Check  if the permissions are granted, before app gets launched.

```
const permissionListener = checkPermissions().then(value => {
      if (value) {
        setPermissionsAllowed(value);
        
      } else {
        console.log('Permissions not allowed ');
      }
      
    });
```

2. If yes, allow them to a specific stack group, if not send them to a screen where they can allow the permissions.

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            // contentStyle: {backgroundColor: ColorPaletteLight.accent100},
          }}>
          {loggedIn ? (
            <Stack.Group>
              {permissionsAllowed ? (
                <Stack.Group>
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="HomeComponents"
                    component={HomeComponents}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="EditProfileView"
                    component={EditProfileView}
                  />
                </Stack.Group>
              ) : (
                <Stack.Group>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Permissions" component={Permissions} />
                </Stack.Group>
              )}
            </Stack.Group>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Group>
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginModify} />
            </Stack.Group>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

This is the error I am getting when I am trying to navigate to a screen in a different stack group
[Navigation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMpLC.png)

Comment: Because both `Stack.Group` cannot exist at the same time, you cannot navigate from `Permissions` to `EditProfileView`

Comment: Your code doesn't have any navigate calls. Add enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement like that:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  {token ? <PublicStack routeName={routeName} /> : <AuthStack />}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Is there any issue in this code?